# How to bypass the upper bound of .Machine$double.xmax in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate MCMC samples using Metropolis-Hastings algorithm in R. I'm trying to find the Bayes estimates of the parameters from a heavy tailed distribution. For that I obtained the expressions for the full conditional posteriors of the parameters, which will be my target density in the MH algorithm.

My code looks like this:

```
target_1=function(param1,param2){...}
target_2=function(param1,param2){...}
```

```
MH=function(startval,target_param1,target_param2,sample)
{
  param_1=rep(0,10000)
  param_2=rep(0,10000)
  
  param_1[1]=startval[1]
  param_2[1]=startval[2]
  
  var_param1=solve(optim(c(param1,param2),LgLik,x=sample,hessian=T)$hessian)[1,1]
  var_param2=solve(optim(c(param1,param2),LgLik,x=sample,hessian=T)$hessian)[2,2]
  
  for(i in 2:10000)
  {
    current_param1=param_1[i-1]
    current_param2=param_2[i-1]
    proposed_param1=rnorm(1,current_param1,sd=sqrt(var_param1))
    a=target_param1(proposed_param1,current_param2)/target_param1(current_param1,current_param2)
    if(runif(1)<a)
    {
      param_1[i]=proposed_param1 #Acceptance
    }else{
      param_1[i]=current_param1  #Rejection
    }
    current_param1=param_1[i]
    proposed_param2=rnorm(1,current_param2,sd=sqrt(var_param2))
    b=target_param2(current_param1,proposed_param2)/target_param2(current_param1,current_param2)
    if(runif(1)<b)
    {
      param_2[i]=proposed_param2 #Acceptance
    }else{
      param_2[i]=current_param2  #Rejection
    }
  }
  return(list(param_1,param_2))
}
```

**Now come to my problem:**

Since, the samples are generated from a heavy tailed distribution, the acceptance probability *a* for some iterations turn out to be *NaN*, because the resulting values in target distribution becomes *Inf*. After some checking, I figured out it is happening because *R* registers any values greater than *1.797693e+308* as *Inf*.

```
.Machine$double.xmax

[1] 1.797693e+308
```

Is there any way we can find a way out from this restrictions? Any suggestions will be highly solicited.

Also, do we have to encounter same kind of problem if we try to code it in Python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1.797693e+308 is an absolutely massive number. If your algorithm is producing numbers that large (or conversely that small), then you need to make updates to the algorithm to handle it / avoid that happening.

Comment: Any suggestions how do I do that? I have tried to use a while loop conditioning that `isTRUE(is.nan(a))==T ` but it's taking forever to converge for the MCMC chain when I'm repeating this function more than 300 times. I even suspect there will always be values more than 1.797693e+308 no matter how many times the while loop runs. That is why I was trying to find any alternate solution.

Comment: Just set any NaN value to that maximum of 1.7+e308.

Comment: @deschen I can't. _a_ is taking the NaN value, which actually needs to be between 0 and 1. And It is coming because _a_ is the ratio of two target densities, and when both of them become _Inf_, a is giving NaN. So I have to control that the target densities don't exceed 1.7e+308

Comment: Yep, that‘s what I meant. Just add an if condition that if a is nan, replace it by an arbitrary high value that is close to the machine limit.